# alternatives to using IN clause

Tags: sql, ssms-2014

I am running the below query:

```
SELECT 
    ReceiptVoucherId, 
    VoucherId, 
    ReceiptId,
    rvtransactionAmount, 
    AmountUsed, 
    TransactionTypeId
FROM 
    [Scratch].[dbo].[LoyaltyVoucherTransactionDetails]
WHERE       
    VoucherId IN 
    (2000723,
    2000738,
    2000774,
    2000873,
    2000888,
    2000924,
    2001023,
    2001038,
    2001074,
    2001173)
```

the aim being to extract the ReceiptVoucherId / VoucherId / ReceiptId /  rvtransactionAmount / AmountUsed / TransactionTypeId data for the list of voucherId's that I have.

My problem here is that my list of VoucherID's is 187k long so an IN clause is not possible as it returns the error:

*Internal error: An expression services limit has been reached*

Can anyone advise on a alternative to doing it this way?

I am using SSMS 2014

Comment: Try using a temp table instead to store the values

Comment: If those voucher Ids are present somewhere else, you could use a sub query as well instead of the actual values. But having that stored in a table like @GiorgosBetsos suggested would be a much cleaner approach.

Comment: Where do these 187K values come *from*? They're surely not a fixed list entered by hand? And where does the result data *go*? It's far too much for someone to directly consume these results. It feels like you've maybe broken up what should be a *single* logical query into multiple procedural steps, and this is one of the intermediate steps. If we could understand the entire end-to-end requirements, we may be able to offer a better overall solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a table containing all this Vouchers (Hopefully you already have one) and then use `IN()` selecting from the table :

```
SELECT 
    ReceiptVoucherId, 
    VoucherId, 
    ReceiptId,
    rvtransactionAmount, 
    AmountUsed, 
    TransactionTypeId
FROM 
    [Scratch].[dbo].[LoyaltyVoucherTransactionDetails]
WHERE       
    VoucherId IN (SELECT VoucherId FROM VourchersTable)
```

Comment: Depending on the privileges, the creation of a "real" table is not that easy... I guess the tab variable or the cte might be a bit easier, no?

Comment: If he doesn't have the privileges, he can just ask his DBA. `CTE` is not a bad idea, but it is for 190k records

Comment: haha U R right... but in a Company I used to work for several years ago, the DBA would happily flip the finger at you and tell you to f*** off. ;-) They can get really nasty if it Comes to privileges. :-) BUT you are right - IF you have to analyze something, you should have the privileges. Concerning the number of records: I recently used a CTE with something like 300K and it worked quite fine... but I used a Script in order to spool the query for me. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You can try the approach:

```
select from mytable where id in (select id from othertable)
```

or left join:

```
select from othertable left join mytable using id
```

not sure what has better performance, also second query could give you empty rows if it is not declared as foreign key.

fly-by-post, feel free to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

insert the vouchers to lookup in a seperate table . lets call it Voucher.

Then this query should do the trick. It does **not** use the IN Clause. but instead it uses Inner join which will be faster.

```
SELECT 
    L.ReceiptVoucherId, 
    L.VoucherId, 
    L.ReceiptId,
    L.rvtransactionAmount, 
    L.AmountUsed, 
    L.TransactionTypeId
FROM 
    [Scratch].[dbo].[LoyaltyVoucherTransactionDetails] L
INNER JOIN dbo.Vouchers V ON L.VoucherId = V.VoucherId
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following works for you:

First of all, declare a variable of type table (or alternatively a temp table) and insert your IDs into it.
Modify your Query to

```
WHERE VoucherID in (SELECT VoucherID FROM @t)
```

Alternatively (but similar write-intensive for your Hands ;-) ) is the creation of a CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT 2000723 UNION ALL SELECT ...)
```

and again the redesign of your "WHERE... IN..." section.

Comment: The creation of a CTE with 187k records? Good luck .